# How to create a Box View app?

Tags: box-view-api

BOX used to allow creation of BOX View apps before. There is no option to select BOX View API today. Did this change or is there a way to switch a Content App to a view app?

Comment: They do have a link on their site saying it has [moved to here](https://box-view.readme.io/reference)

Comment: True and it also redirects you to create an api key [here](https://box-content.readme.io/docs/how-to-get-an-api-key).However, when you try to create an app, there is no option to select Box View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to an email from Box Customer Services, they are no longer providing the View API for free users.

So if you are a free user, that is why you can no longer create a View application.

If you are a paid developer or trying to replace a View Application you are advised to contact Customer Services.