# Box View Developer, Cannot create a View Application

Tags: box, box-view-api

This question has been asked by someone else ([How to create a Box View app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35328500/3482632)) but was down voted for some obscure reason and so I will try and explain more.

I have a box developer account. According to their guide: https://box-content.readme.io/docs when you click on "Create Application", there should be two options, one to create a Box Content app and one for Box View app.

Last year I followed this guide and created a View app successfully following this guide.

However, I tried to do this again recently, and there is no longer an option for creating a "View" app.

If you create a "Box Content App", there are two radio buttons, one for Content API and the other for View, however it defaults to the Content option and the radio buttons are disabled in both IE and Chrome.

Is anyone aware of the change and whether it is possible to create a View application and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

Someone I work with checked with Box and according to an email from Box Customer Services, they are no longer providing the View API for free users.

Free users, like me, can no longer create a View application.